# How to highlight only the text on hover, not whitespace? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to highlight on hover, but it highlights entire div instead of just text. I tried using an "a tag" but do not want a reference link obviously. im sure this is simple, but im wasting too much time on trial and error. tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an inline tag like `<span>`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text in a `span` then highlight that.